# Android: Overlapping two views (intentionally!)

Tags: android, android-layout

just wondering is it possible to overlap two elements?

This is an illustration of what im trying to achieve:

[image]

Basically its a circle ImageButton, which center lies on the corner of a rectangle. How should I go about positioning it? Can I use RelativeLayout or something else?

Comment: I'd wrap both views in a RelativeLayout and align the overlapped one to the right and bottom of parent.

Comment: If you provide a link to your image someone will edit it into the question for you.

Comment: http://chesnutcase.heliohost.org/derpbox/overlayout.png

Comment: the rectangle is actually a form that contains fields(textViews).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a RelativeLayout for the blue box, align your ImageView to the top-right corner, and then use negative margins to push it over the bounding box. Here's a sample illustrating the general idea:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
I played with this a bit more, and you have to set android:clipChildren="false" on the parent of the RelativeLayout. Here's a more complete sample:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_margin="100dp">
        <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well, it worked in terms of positioning, but something unexpected came up.

http://chesnutcase.heliohost.org/derpbox/overlayout2.png

as you can see, the red button got cut off, although its pretty much at the right position.

Comment: Try setting android:clipToPadding="false" on the RelativeLayout.

Comment: ok, this time it revealed more of itself, but 3 quarters of it still hidden. what does it do anyway? also, if it helps, this box is a relative layout by itself, the whole xml is a relative layout too.
http://chesnutcase.heliohost.org/derpbox/overlayout3.png

Comment: Ah, you have to set android:clipChildren="false" on the parent of the RelativeLayout, so that it is allowed to draw outside of its bounding box. I've edited my answer above to include this. You will have to leave the android:clipToPadding="false" as well, as you have padding set on your RelativeLayout.

Comment: And to explain what these do, android:clipToPadding sets whether a ViewGroup's children are clipped at the padding box rather than at the bounding box. This defaults to true for most ViewGroups that I'm aware of. android:clipChildren sets whether a ViewGroup's children can draw outside of their bounding boxes. You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren and here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipToPadding

Comment: Glad I could help! And no worries, accepting as the answer is just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution is taking margin of ImageView in negative values(e.g. -40dp).
But it works only in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach would be to use two transparent image views. These imageviews will be to the top and right of the blue layout. Set background of this image views as #00000000 to make them transparent.