# add ImageView on Horizontal line in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create layout which contain horizontal line(dotted) and 
on that line i want to add small image which is horizontally centered

this is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget38"
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <View
         android:layout_width="51dp"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:background="@color/gray" />

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
         android:src="@drawable/image"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

added negative margin to place that image on line. but my problem is image (part above line) upper part is not visible .

I tried using framelayout also.

but getting same result

**I dont want to use constraint layout**

I tried this link 
[Android: Overlapping two views (intentionally!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350962/android-overlapping-two-views-intentionally)

https://www.android-examples.com/overlap-view-by-putting-another-view-above-in-relativelayout-android/

how to do it

Comment: can you post expected result image?

Comment: i want the same result getting with above xml. just i want to display complete image. currently getting half part of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give top margin to the view. Your view is placed at the top of Relative layout. So when you are trying to put image on line it is going outside of Relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout for this purpose like below:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widget38"
                android:layout_width="51dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >
                <View
                    android:layout_width="51dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

You must set width of Linear to match_parent.

Comment: You must set width of Linear to match_parent. That is invisible because your linearlayout width is same as your view.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget38"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```